# Fetch Google Map URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Google Map on a Wordpress website. The map is loaded via the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

If you click in the left bottom corner on 'Google', the location opens in a new tab in Google Maps (eg https://www.google.com/maps/@10.8396607,4.7913165,11.5z?hl=en-US)

I would like this to happen when the entire map is clicked, so not only when the 'Google' icon is clicked.

So, I know how to do that with Javascript, but the problem is that I cannot seem to fetch the URL from the page.

I've tried many selectors, but it just doesn't seem to be able to get that URL.
One of the things I've tried: console.log($(".acf-map a").attr('href'));

I've been able to fetch all other URLs on the page, but not the one generated in the map.

[HTML generating the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oop45.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a trigger for the "click" event directly on the variable "map", instead of setting it onto the marker. You should find everything you need here [Link to maps reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventListeners)

```
map.addlistener('click', function(){
     window.open(yoururl); //or something similar
```

});

should do the trick.

p.s. let me know if the solution works for you, I don't have a PC to try by myself

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

The problem though is that I don't have the 'yoururl' parameter.

I need to fetch that URL (which points to the full map in Google Maps: e.g.https://www.google.com/maps/@10.8396607,4.7913165,11.5z?hl=en-US) , but I can't seem to fetch it for every map individually.

Comment: the 'yoururl' parameter can be a fixed URL like www.google.com, you don't need to retrieve it using your code
E.G.

map.addlistener('click', function(){
     window.open("www.youtube.com"); //or something similar
});

Comment: I do need to retrieve it, because I need it for many different maps on my website (not just 1).

A unique URL is generated for many different maps (and thus many different locations) all over the website, and I need to automatically retrieve that specific URL in all the different Google Maps on the website.